# How to get the full URL from an SPWEB

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I have a VB console application.

I would like to get the absolute URL of the page.

***Here is my current code:***

```
Using siteCollectSPSite As New SPSite("http://mySite")
Dim blogPostSpList As SPList

'Get only the subsite of <locale/blogs>
Using blogSiteSPWeb As SPWeb = siteCollectSPSite.OpenWeb("/blogs")

For Each subsite As SPWeb In blogSiteSPWeb.Webs
    Console.WriteLine("Subsite title:   " & subsite.Url)
    '......
Next
```

**Right now, what I get is: `http://mySite/blogs/myblog1`**

What I want to get is the full URL: **http://mySite/blogs/myblog1/default.aspx**

How can I get the "default.aspx"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your problem is that SPWeb doesnt actually have a 'page' as such. Default.aspx is simply one page inside the SPWeb container.

You can modify/read the default page using publishingWeb if you have the publishing feature enabled otherwise try this:

http://curia.me/post/2011/05/20/SharePoint-how-change-the-default-page-of-a-SPWeb.aspx

Comment: Hi Luke! thanks for your reply. However, the site where I am trying to get the full URL is not a PublishingWeb. :(

Comment: take a look at the link then, it has the other option for doing this

Answer (score 1):

WelcomePage is the property of SPFolder type so to get the full url , you have to use :

```
subsite.Url + "/" + subsite.RootFolder.WelcomePage;
```

Comment: what do you mean "has no value"? `null`? `string.empty`?

Comment: @moontear it is an empty string

Comment: This worked for me in team sites as well as publishing sites.

Answer (score 1):

SPFolder.WelcomePage should have worked. If it didn't you need to set the "vti_welcomepage" in the properties of the Folder list item. This is what MS does under the hood.

```
    if (this.m_strRedirectUrl == null)
    {
        string text = (string)this.Properties["vti_welcomepage"];
        if (text == null)
        {
            text = string.Empty;
        }
        this.m_strRedirectUrl = text;
    }
    return this.m_strRedirectUrl;
```

Comment: I know - also check out dot.net obfuscator, same thing as ILSpy.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have a look at it.